# Simplex noise magic numbers explanation

Tags: math, graphics, glsl

I was reading The Book of Shader's chapter about [simplex noise](https://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php#11/lava-lamp.frag) (click for full code), and had difficulty understanding a few magic numbers used here. This will not be a bug related thread, but should make sense under SO's community criteria.

See these lines:

```
    vec3 p = permute( permute( i.y + vec3(0.0, i1.y, 1.0 ))
        + i.x + vec3(0.0, i1.x, 1.0 ));
    // random numbers for gradient generation

    // element wise: 0.5 - x ^ 4
    // use max clamp element wise: if x < 0 then m = 0 (i.e. the gradient from the vertex is 0)

    // x1, x2, x3: 3 verteces of triangle simplex
    // dot product is the distance from v to simpelx verteces
    vec3 m = max(0.5 - vec3(dot(x0,x0), dot(x12.xy,x12.xy), dot(x12.zw,x12.zw)), 0.0);
    m = m*m ;
    m = m*m ;

    vec3 x = 2.0 * fract(p * C.www) - 1.0;  // gradient? 2 * fract(x / 41) - 1, in [-1, 1]
    vec3 h = abs(x) - 0.5;                  // in [-0.5, 0.5]
    vec3 ox = floor(x + 0.5);               // in [-1, 1]
    vec3 a0 = x - ox;
    // (x - ox) ^ 2 + (abs(x) - .5) ^ 2
    m *= 1.79284291400159 - 0.85373472095314 * ( a0 * a0 + h * h ); // ???
```

Meanwhile I understand in another [java implementation](http://staffwww.itn.liu.se/~stegu/simplexnoise/simplexnoise.pdf) they used a precomputed 2d array table and a random index to look up gradients, the above lines don't make much sense for me. I guess `m` stands for weights for each vertex's gradient contribution, and the rest remains a puzzle.

Hope there could be resources / comments help me out on understanding this snippet.

Comment: Turns out as `p` is a random vector, you can replace the fancy calculation below with a constant and it doesn't affect output much. They have no secrets here, they are just random.